# WiFi and Bluetooth can't work simultaneously!

Tags: networking, internet

Issue:
My laptop disconnects from the network (not only the internet, I am not even able to ping the router) after few seconds when I am using my Bluetooth Mouse (Logitech MX Anywhere 2S). This could potentially extend to all Bluetooth devices but I don't have another device to confirm.
If I disconnect from the network and reconnect, the connection lasts for few seconds till the issue happen again.
If I diconnect the mouse, the connectivity start working normally without issues.
This doesn't happen when I am running Windows (on the Same laptop), so this is a configuration issue.
If it helps, I am using Elementary OS 5 (based on 18.05LTS, 64 bit). Laptop Sony Vaio

Answer (score 1):

Try this command `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"` and reboot.

If it doesn't help, you can revert the setting by `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf`

The command will make bluetooth and WiFi coexist. Work at the same time.

Comment: This helped..just not in the way you intended. In trying to restart the network I restarted the whole laptop and then I noticed issue was resolved...but as as soon as i connected my Bluetooth mouse the issue occurred again. I disconnected the mouse and network worked again no issues. Please check the updated question.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try this command `sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"` and reboot. 
If it works use the following command to be permanent `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf`

Comment: Thanks, It worked! but what did that code do? Also I want to "Accept" you second answer here as the right solution but the buttons are not there. What to do?

Comment: This just made my (quarantine) life much better. I can now plug my BT speaker and listen to Spotify (online) on Elementary. You sir, rock. Thx!

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf` reverts the setting, not makes it permanent.