# Bluetooth mouse Logitech M535 stopped working, it appears and disappers in a list of available devices in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, mouse, logitech

My bluetooth mouse Logitech M535 stopped working suddenly in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I can't connect to it anymore. I removed it from a list of Bluetooth devices in [blueman](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134363/63516) and tried to search for it and add again back in hope it will help to solve the issue. Unfortunately, each time I click a mouse button to make it discoverable by operating system it appears in the list of available devices and then disappears immediately like shown in the picture:

[image: bluetooth mouse logitech m535 is not discoverable anymore]

I also tried to pair the mouse on another PC with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS — the same result. Another interesting thing that after the issue occurred I booted into Windows 10 where my mouse hadn't worked previously and...it started to work there. Not sure that it might be related but it seems very weird.

I don't know what I can do and which logs to check in order to state what the problem is. Looking for similar questions on bluetooth mouse issues wasn't not really helpful. That's why I am asking for help.

These are outputs of a couple commands related to bluetooth adapters, I guess:

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ hciconfig --all
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: BC:17:B8:CB:91:8D  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:49836 acl:128 sco:0 events:4404 errors:0
    TX bytes:781983 acl:128 sco:0 commands:3696 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'merisa'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Revision: 0x100
    LMP Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Subversion: 0x100
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

**UPDATE: 2022-01-04**

I started the system from live USB (Kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS), installed Blueman:

```
sudo apt install blueman
```

and was able to discover the mouse on the third attempt and pair it. So now I am updating the answer from live session with working mouse:

[image: working bluetooth mouse in live usb session]

Does it mean that something is broken in Bluetooth configuration of my existing operating system?

This is what I've got from live session:

```
$ sudo cat /var/lib/bluetooth/BC\:17\:B8\:CB\:91\:8D/34\:88\:5D\:AF\:FB\:85/info
[General]
Name=Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535
Class=0x002580
SupportedTechnologies=BR/EDR;
Trusted=true
Blocked=false
Services=00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;

[LinkKey]
Key=87BEA06887EA46DE046A3B25ABF1F9BF
Type=4
PINLength=0

[DeviceID]
Source=2
Vendor=1133
Product=45078
Version=4611
```

Comment: Have you checked the battery?

Comment: @Bovine, sure. I replaced three batteries, and I get the same result. Moreover, as I already told, mouse is working in Windows.

Comment: Do you use a wireless, or wired, Internet connection? Do you know how to access the admin web page in your router?

Comment: @heynnema I use wireless Internet connection and, yes, I can access admin web page of my router.

Comment: Check your router settings for something that sounds like "Bluetooth coexistence" and make sure it's enabled. It's probably in the wireless tab/settings. See if that helps.

Comment: @ezze Status please...

Comment: @heynnema My router is Keenetic Speedster KN-3010, and I didn't find any settings related to Bluetooth there. Why do you think that the issue may be caused by a router? The mouse worked in Ubuntu for a half of an year, and it works in Windows 10 at the moment. So I don't see how router settings can be linked with bluetooth mouse.

Comment: The coexistence is probably in the wireless setup portion. I couldn't find a user manual for clarification. What band do you use to connect 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz? What channels are set for each band in the router? See https://help.keenetic.com/hc/en-us/articles/213968749-Ways-to-increase-connection-speed-bandwidth-and-stability-of-your-Wi-Fi-network and https://help.keenetic.com/hc/en-us/articles/213968709-What-affects-Wi-Fi-networks-The-possible-sources-of-interference- and search for "bluetooth" in each document.

Comment: "Bluetooth coexistence" may be shown as "20/40mhz coexistence". In regards to my question about band/channel... see https://help.keenetic.com/hc/en-us/articles/213968769-How-to-scan-a-Wi-Fi-network-and-determine-the-freest-channel-. Also get yourself a copy of LinSSID at https://sourceforge.net/projects/linssid/.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry for keeping silence. My router is configured to work on both 2.4GHz and 5Ghz...but I simply turned it off in order to check whether it affects bluetooth mouse. Same result. Moreover, it was working with Ubuntu 20.04 perfectly, and nothing had changed in router settings since then. I didn't find anything related to "bluetooth coexistence" in settings and now I'm not sure it's relevant to my issue. I also tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129820/63516) and it also didn't help me. What do I need LinSSID for?

Comment: @ezze So you physically powered off the router, and the mouse acted the same, yes? And the problem occurs on two different computers, yes? Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and see if it works there. Report back. (forget my request to install `solaar`.)

Comment: @heynnema, yes, I turned it off physically, and nothing changed — mouse is visible in a list of available devices for a moment, and then disappears. I tested it (not very hard) a few days ago on another computer and faced the same issue. Unfortunately, I can't re-test there at the moment.
I installed `solaar` from Ubuntu repository but when I start it shows me an empty window with "Select a device" message. There are no available devices in the list even when I click or move the mouse.

Comment: @ezze Sorry for the bum steer on installing `solaar`. It's not for bluetooth mice. You can uninstall it. Try the Ubuntu Live and report back.

Comment: @heynnema I'll re-test with live USB later and back to you with results.

Comment: @heynnema I updated the question, got my mouse working in live session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, it must be obvious to anyone who's using Bluetooth mouse for half of year or so like me...but I was able to make the mouse discoverable after my experiments in live session just by clicking Bluetooth button at the bottom of the mouse. Since then it remains in the list of available devices constantly and I can connect it easily.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me - I suspect there's some interference, or a bad kernel update.